# JavaScripts Parameter Options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to know that how can I create an object or options (whatever it is).

I have created a js file with functions named popupModal()

for now, I'm using this function like this

```
popupModal(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,param6)
```

while calling if I don't want some parameter I have to write this.

```
popupModal(param1,undefined,param3,undefined,undefined,param6)
```

can someone please tell me how can I modify my function so whenever I use this function I can call it like

```
popupModal ({
param2: someValue,
param6: someValue
});
```

Comment: Make it accept a single parameter e.g. `function popupModal(options)` - you'll then assume that the incoming `options` variable is an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require you need to accept a single object as an argument.

```js
popupModal({
  param2: 'foo',
  param6: 'bar'
});

function popupModal(settings) {
  console.log(settings.param2);
  console.log(settings.param6);
}
```

If you wanted some parameters to be optional then you can define an object within your function which contains the default values. Then you can use jQuery's `$.extend()` method to overwrite it with the user defined settings:

```js
popupModal({
  param2: 'foo',
  param6: 'bar'
});

function popupModal(settings) {
  var defaults = {
    param1: '1',
    param2: '2',
    param3: '3',
    param4: '4',
    param5: '5',
    param6: '6',
  }
  
  settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);
  
  console.log(settings.param1);
  console.log(settings.param2);
  console.log(settings.param3);
  console.log(settings.param4);
  console.log(settings.param5);
  console.log(settings.param6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just one more thing if you can help:
as you know, now we can set optional parameters with default values...if there any way to create an optional parameter with some selected value?
just like bootstrap modal...
it has function called .modal() which accepts only 'show' || 'hide' || 'toggle' || 'dispose'

is there any way make our own?

Comment: To do that you could determine the type of the argument passed in using `typeof()`. If it's an object, perform the logic in the example. If it's a string do whatever other operation you require.

Comment: can you please give me any example?  @Rory

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter or object as a parameter and you should check if the parameter is `undefined` or `null` before implementing them.
if you forgot to check `undefined` or `null` values, issues may occur. So, don't forget to check the `undefined` or `null` values of the received parameters.

```js
    function popupModal(o) {
        if (o.param1 !== undefined)
            console.log(o.param1.name, o.param1.roll);
        if (o.param1 !== undefined)
            console.log(o.param2.address, o.param2.city);
        if (o.url !== undefined)
            console.log(o.url);
    }
    
    popupModal({
        param1: {
            name: "hello",
            roll: 11
        },
        param2: {
            address: "United State",
            city: "New York"
        },
        url: "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    });
```